# Importing FishEye keystore issue

Tags: keystore, fisheye, atlassian-fisheye

One of my customers had an existing FishEye installation, I advised them to back it up into a zip file so I could import it into our FishEye instance. The import went fine but now the FishEye service does not start complaining about the keystore and config.xml:

```
ERROR - Problem configuring P4 executable
com.cenqua.fisheye.config.ConfigException: P4 executable does not exist at configured location: /opt/atlassian/fisheye-data/C:\Program Files\Perforce\p4.exe, using 'p4' instead, make sure it is on your PATH.

ERROR - Could not create webserver: Cannot find the file [/opt/atlassian/fecru-4.5.2/C:\keystore\test\somename.jks]. Please check the 'keystore' attribute in the <ssl> element in config.xml
```

I checked and the backup file has that reference but the imported version does not have any reference to that jks file. Here's the config.xml of the destination machine after the import was done:

```
<config control-bind="127.0.0.1:8059" version="1.0">
<!-- see example-config.xml and config.xsd for more documentation -->
<web-server>
    <http bind=":8060"/>
</web-server>
<security allow-anon="true" allow-cru-anon="true"/>
<repository-defaults>
    <linker/>
    <allow/>
    <tarball enabled="false" maxFileCount="0"/>
    <security allow-anon="true"/>
</repository-defaults>
```

Can someone please shed some lights on this?

Answer (score 0):

Keystore is used for HTTPS(SSL) protocol. It's not backed by Fisheye backup process simply because it's out of Fisheye's installation directory. Furthermore, I'm not sure if some people would call it a security issue if Fisheye backed up SSL certificates.

In your case, basing on a name of this certificate (`test\somename.jks`) I guess somebody was testing something and it's safe to simply remove it. If you did happen to use HTTPS I believe you need to regenerate certificates and set up HTTPS once more. 
https://confluence.atlassian.com/fisheye/fisheye-ssl-configuration-298976938.html